# Visibility attribute question

Tags: jquery, html, css

What is the difference between

`$("#myid").attr("style", "visibility: hidden")`

and

`$("#myid").css("visibility", "hidden")`

?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Doing this:

```
$("#myid").attr("style", "visibility: hidden")
```

Will leave **only** this style attribute, while doing this:

```
$("#myid").css("visibility", "hidden")
```

Will **add** (or set) this style attribute.

Here's an example, the first will **always** result in this:

```
style="visibility: hidden;"
```

The second just adds `visibility` so your style may now be:

```
style="width: 50px; color: red; visibility: hidden;"
```

Answer (score 6):

<strike>Nothing. Just two ways to accomplish the same goal.</strike>

The first will overwrite any existing style settings. If you had:

```
<div style="font-weight: bold;" />
```

It would become:

```
<div sytle="visibility: hidden;" />
```

The second will add the visibility setting to the existing styles. So:

```
<div style="font-weight: bold;" />
```

Woudl become:

```
<div style="font-weight: bold; visibility: hidden;" />
```

If there's no style attribute already set, then the two will produce the same end result.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>There isn't really any difference.</strike> $.css() is just a shortcut method for accessing the css style attribute of a dom element.

http://api.jquery.com/css/

EDIT: As justin pointed out, there *is* a difference in that the .attr() method will overwrite any existing style attributes.