# JQuery remove styles added

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I am new to Javascript, 
I am using Backbone
So I add a style like this(to a link when its clicked)

```
     $(eventC.target.parentNode).css('border', '1px solid red');
```

I want the previous link to be cleared of the red border I added when I click on new link

I looked at link below
[jQuery - remove style added with .css() function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4036857/jquery-remove-style-added-with-css-function)

So in essence I want to do this:

```
$(OLDLINK).css('border', 'none');
$(NewLINK).css('border', '1px solid red');
```

with events I get from  backbone

Is there a simple way to do  this? or is this approach just wrong?

Comment: offtopic.use classes instead of setting style to you elements.

Comment: @AlekseiBulgak I would say that is perfectly on topic, and should be an answer ;)

Comment: Yes thanks I tried so  many different ways, and this is so much more simple

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest using a CSS class for adding the border and to add / remove it like below

CSS:

```
.borderRed
{
  border : 1px solid red;
}
```

jQuery:

```
//remove border from old link
$('.borderRed').removeClass('borderRed');

// add border in new link
$(eventC.target.parentNode).addClass('borderRed');
```

Comment: Aah!  YESSSSSS! thats great!

Comment: Semantic class names are usually a better choice than classes that describe the style. So in this case it could be something like `.activeLink`.

Answer (score 2):

If I clearly understand your question, you need something like this

```
var container = $("div.parent").on("click", "a", function(){
    $(this).addClass("selected");
    container.find("a").not($(this)).removeClass("selected");
});
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bbdL7cpL/)

Answer (score 1):

This solution may be as:

```
Backbone.View.extend ({

 events: {
   "event-which-delete-border a.link":"changeLink",
   "event-which-add-border a.link":"changeLink"
 },
changeLink:function(event) {

 if (event.type == 'event-which-delete-border') {
   $('a.link').css('border', 'none');
 } else if (event.type == 'event-which-add-border')
   $('a.link').css('border', '1px solid red');
 }

})
```

In this example, words 'event-which-delete-border' and 'event-which-add-border' may be all events from JavaScript, such as 'click' 'mouseover' and etc

Answer (score 1):

You can use any of these three methods-

1. you can use the .attr() to change the style of the element.

   ```
   $(OLDLINK).attr('style', 'border: none');
   $(NewLINK).attr('style','border: 1px solid red');
   ```

   this method is safe to cross browser defects.
2. the one you are using.
3. you can use the method as explained by Bhushan above.

the difference between these could be found here- [Visibility attribute question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2690865/visibility-attribute-question)